# How do I transfer a value from one page to another in hidden parameters instead of a querystring?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

What's wrong with this code?

Source page : Default.aspx

```
 <form id="form1" action ="Default2.aspx" method="post" runat="server">
            <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Merchant Id</td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="SRCSITEID" Text="T521" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
            </tr>
               </table>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="Submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>          
    </form>
```

Destination page : Default2.aspx

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

    </div>
    </form>
```

Default2.aspx.vb

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Try
            TextBox1.Text = Request("SRCSITEID").ToString()
        Catch
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: Change the textboxes to Html Textboxes and remove the runat="server" from the form Tag and it shall work.Asp textboxes cannot exist without asp form{runat="server"} and asp forms cannot submit to another page.

Comment: To yell has the same meaning as to shout, or to cry. It means to talk in a loud voice. Writing everything in capitals is the internet equivalent of that. It makes the text hard to read, and some may find it rude. In other words, don't use the Caps Lock key.

Answer (score 1):

You could try

Page1

```
Session["someKey"] = ValueFromPage1;
```

and in Page2

```
var valueFromPage1 = Session["someKey"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Cross Page Posting ([MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx))

It's like doing a postback only you post back to a completely different page.

Example Code:

```
If Not Page.PreviousPage Is Nothing Then
   Dim SourceTextBox As TextBox
   SourceTextBox = CType(PreviousPage.FindControl("SRCSITEID"), TextBox)
   If Not SourceTextBox Is Nothing Then
       TextBox1.Text = SourceTextBox.Text
   End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Request.Form("SRCSITEID")
```

because you use post method